# REF001: <ChunkInTransaction>filepath has been owned by transaction

Tags: dolphindb

REF001: filepath has been owned by transaction

When I try to concurrently write data to the same partition, it throw me this error.

Answer (score 0):

In DolphinDB, the same partition cannot be written by multiple writers concurrently. After a partition is locked by a certain transaction A, the system will immediately throw the above exception when another transaction B tries to lock the partition again.